# JQPlot - No plot target specified

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

I'm trying to draw jqplot with the following code:

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {



        var line1 = var line1 =[["10.01.2011",3.9990],["11.01.2011",3.9910],["12.01.2011",4.0140],["13.01.2011",3.9940],["14.01.2011",3.9050],["17.01.2011",3.9340],["18.01.2011",3.9520],["19.01.2011",3.8980],["20.01.2011",3.8690],["21.01.2011",3.8830],["24.01.2011",3.8550],["25.01.2011",3.8480],["26.01.2011",3.8190],["27.01.2011",3.8440],["28.01.2011",3.8260],["31.01.2011",3.8060],["01.02.2011",3.7970],["02.02.2011",3.8060],["03.02.2011",3.8110],["04.02.2011",3.8640],["07.02.2011",3.8750],["08.02.2011",3.8640],["09.02.2011",3.8480],["11.02.2011",3.8570],["14.02.2011",3.8880],["15.02.2011",3.88],["16.02.2011",3.8520],["17.02.2011",3.8590],["18.02.2011",3.8690],["22.02.2011",3.8440],["23.02.2011",3.8080],["24.02.2011",3.7410],["25.02.2011",3.7460],["28.02.2011",3.7550],["01.03.2011",3.7520],["02.03.2011",3.76],["03.03.2011",3.7420],["04.03.2011",3.7430],["07.03.2011",3.7330],["08.03.2011",3.7260],["09.03.2011",3.76],["10.03.2011",3.7910],["11.03.2011",3.79]]; 

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
            title: 'Default Date Axis',
            axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer } },
            series: [{ lineWidth: 4, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is generated through some C# code, but at the end the page source looks like the presented code.
The chart is not drawn and jquery throws this exception: `No plot target specified`.

Any clue for that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Be sure that your HTML includes an element (usually a div) with an Id of `chart1`.

The jqplot source code goes like this:

```
this.init = function(target, data, options) {

    this.target = $('#'+target);

    ....

    if (!this.target.get(0)) {
        throw "No plot target specified";
    }

    ....
}
```

It appears that is the only place in the code that particular error occurs. Note that the `#` character is prepended to the `target`, hence why target needs to be a valid Id.

Answer (score 1):

Fully functional HTML page with your code. Just replace "../../libs/jQuery.jqPlot.1.0.9/" to point to your local jqPlot installation folder.

Remark inclusion of the required **jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js** plugin! It took me a while to figure out the chart is not rendered without it :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>iqPlot Sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../libs/jQuery.jqPlot.1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../libs/jQuery.jqPlot.1.0.9/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../libs/jQuery.jqPlot.1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../libs/jQuery.jqPlot.1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var line1 = [["10.01.2011",3.9990],["11.01.2011",3.9910],["12.01.2011",4.0140],["13.01.2011",3.9940],["14.01.2011",3.9050],["17.01.2011",3.9340],["18.01.2011",3.9520],["19.01.2011",3.8980],["20.01.2011",3.8690],["21.01.2011",3.8830],["24.01.2011",3.8550],["25.01.2011",3.8480],["26.01.2011",3.8190],["27.01.2011",3.8440],["28.01.2011",3.8260],["31.01.2011",3.8060],["01.02.2011",3.7970],["02.02.2011",3.8060],["03.02.2011",3.8110],["04.02.2011",3.8640],["07.02.2011",3.8750],["08.02.2011",3.8640],["09.02.2011",3.8480],["11.02.2011",3.8570],["14.02.2011",3.8880],["15.02.2011",3.88],["16.02.2011",3.8520],["17.02.2011",3.8590],["18.02.2011",3.8690],["22.02.2011",3.8440],["23.02.2011",3.8080],["24.02.2011",3.7410],["25.02.2011",3.7460],["28.02.2011",3.7550],["01.03.2011",3.7520],["02.03.2011",3.76],["03.03.2011",3.7420],["04.03.2011",3.7430],["07.03.2011",3.7330],["08.03.2011",3.7260],["09.03.2011",3.76],["10.03.2011",3.7910],["11.03.2011",3.79]]; 
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
        title: 'Default Date Axis',
        axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer } },
        series: [{ lineWidth: 4, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```